# Javascript setDate Confusion

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a date object that is 90 days from a specified date for use in a date comparison, but am not getting the correct dates.  I have isolated my problem to the code shown below.

```
var now = new Date();
var beforeNow = new Date();
var afterNow = new Date();
var myDate = new Date();
var beforeMyDate = new Date();
var afterMyDate = new Date();

beforeNow.setDate(now.getDate() - 90);
afterNow.setDate(now.getDate() + 90);

myDate.setFullYear(2011, 10, 22); // set to Nov 22, 2011

beforeMyDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 90); // set to 90 days before Nov 22, 2011
afterMyDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 90); // set to 90 days after Nov 22, 2011
```

The above is resulting in:

*beforeMyDate*: Fri Dec 23 2011 08:46:18 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

*myDate*: Tue Nov 22 2011 08:46:18 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

*afterMyDate*: Wed Jun 20 2012 08:46:18 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LnmpR/9/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the same base time to the `beforeMyDate` and `afterMyDate` `Date` instances. Currently, you're adding/removing 90 days of the **current** date (`new Date()` without parameters returns the current time).

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LnmpR/12/

```
var now = new Date();
var beforeNow = new Date();
var afterNow = new Date();
var myDate = new Date();
var beforeMyDate;
var afterMyDate;

beforeNow.setDate(now.getDate() - 90);
afterNow.setDate(now.getDate() + 90);

myDate.setFullYear(2011, 10, 22);    // set to Nov 22, 2011
beforeMyDate = new Date(myDate);     // Set base to myDate
afterMyDate = new Date(myDate);      // Set base to myDate

beforeMyDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 90); // set to 90 days before Nov 22, 2011
afterMyDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 90); // set to 90 days after Nov 22, 2011
```

The values of `beforeNow` and `afterNow` might also be off by a few milliseconds, because all of them are new, parameterless instances of the `Date` object.

Comment: Thanks very much Rob. Have yourself a great weekend!